# Downloading large zip files in python from a RESTAPI url results in a downloading just 1KB files

Tags: python, rest, api, curl, subprocess

I am downloading large .zip extension files from a restapi URL endpoint(which is a corporate private URL) using requests in python and the files downloaded end up being downloaded for 1KB and are thus invalid.
1. I have used tried urllib library too for the same but ended up in the same
   1Kb file downloads which are invalid.
2. The URL endpoint downloads the file when the URL is hit from the browser 
   but does not download using python code.

1. I have tried using the urllib library in python which did not work.
2. I have used clint library too but that too didn't work.

```
    with open(dir+"/"+dict['title'], 'wb') as dumpstate_file:
        print("downloading")
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
            if(chunk):
                dumpstate_file.write(chunk)
```

```
    with open(dir+"/"+dict['title'], 'wb') as out:
        total_length = int(r.headers.get('content-length'))
        for ch in progress.bar(r.iter_content(chunk_size = 2391975), expected_size=(total_length/1024) + 1):
            if ch:
                out.write(ch)
```

```
    r = http.request('GET', url, preload_content=False)
    print("downloading")
    with open(dir+"/"+dict['title'], 'wb') as out:
        while True:
            data = r.read(8192)
            if not data:
                break
            out.write(data)
```

There are no error messages.
The problem here is that the files downloaded here are of just 1KB and invalid.

**UPDATE**

I found a solution to this issue. I ran a curl request for the same in my anaconda prompt and the zip file downloaded successfully.

This is the curl request I ran:

```
curl --data-urlencode "singleId=alok3.singh" --data-urlencode "appId=SRI_N_TOOL" --data-urlencode "userLang=KO" --data-urlencode "serviceCode=GET_FILE" --data-urlencode "divisionCode=00" --data-urlencode "param={'divisionCode':'25','docId':'00DFOJ57StPMWL1000','title':'CallerId[1].zip','fileId':'00DFOJ57LtPMWL1000'}" -o CallerId[1].zip http://{private company url}/fileapi/getFile.do
```

I am not sure how to use this particular piece of code in my python script as i need to automate these downloads.

**FURTHER UPDATE**

I used python's subprocess function to use this curl request I have mentioned above in the update.

Here is the code for the subprocess call:
This below code works completely fine and downloads the complete file

```
subprocess.call(["curl", "--data-urlencode", "singleId=alok3.singh", "--data-urlencode", "appId=SRI_N_TOOL", "--data-urlencode", "userLang=KO", "--data-urlencode", "serviceCode=GET_FILE", "--data-urlencode", "divisionCode=00", "--data-urlencode", "param={'divisionCode':'25','docId':'00DF','title':'hello.zip','fileId':'tPMWL'}","-o","hello.zip","https://privateurl"])
```

But there is a catch in this:
When I replace the docId with a string variable which contains the docId, the download doesn't work.

```
docId='00DF'
subprocess.call(["curl", "--data-urlencode", "singleId=alok3.singh", "--data-urlencode", "appId=SRI_N_TOOL", "--data-urlencode", "userLang=KO", "--data-urlencode", "serviceCode=GET_FILE", "--data-urlencode", "divisionCode=00", "--data-urlencode", "param={'divisionCode':'25','docId':docId,'title':'hello.zip','fileId':'tPMWL'}","-o","hello.zip","https://privateurl"])
```

**SOLUTION**

The requirement here needed here was to use json.dumps() and json.loads() for the params to extract the variables.

```
param = json.dumps({
        'divisionCode':'25',
        'docId':docId,
        'title':title,
        'fileId':title
    })

args = ["curl", "--data-urlencode", "singleId=alok3.singh", "--data-urlencode", "appId=SRI_N_TOOL", "--data-urlencode", "userLang=KO", "--data-urlencode", "serviceCode=GET_FILE", "--data-urlencode", "divisionCode=00", "--data-urlencode", "param={0}".format(json.loads(param)),"-o","CallerId[1].zip","http://private url"]

subprocess.call(args)
```

Comment: Have you tried with `urllib` or `requests` module ? take a look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22776/8393004])

Comment: Yes, I have tried them already and it results in the same issue. I already went through the answer you have tagged in the comment and it doesn't help.

Comment: I have implemented the code as in this[https://stackoverflow.com/a/22776/5863561] and I get the zip files downloaded which are empty

Comment: Are you sure the endpoint returns the zip file content? or it just returns the URL to the zip file? Are you able to download the file if you copy-paste the URL in the browser?

Comment: yes, it returns the zip file. And yes I am able to download the file by copying and pasting the URL in the browser.